# Wampp server se ha muerto por culpa de un PHP error

Tags: php, windows, wampserver

¡Hola muy buenas! Por alguna razón, el servidor Wampp no quiere funcionar por culpa de un error de PHP. He intentado solucionarlo pero no me hace caso, os adjunto por fotos los errores y como lo he intentado solucionar:

**Primer error**

[image: First look of the problem:]

**Error real**
[image: The real problem]

**Intento de solución**
[image: This is what I tried to do to solve the problem]

Realmente intenté todo, como se puede ver, pero SuiteCRM y otras aplicaciones simplemente murieron debido a este problema. Por favor ayuda.

Comment: Hola. Te está diciendo que no añadas cosas de wamp en las variables de entorno. Probaste borrar ese registro del path?

Comment: Además, c:/wamp64 no es un path valido de Windows.  Debe ser c:\wamp64 .

Comment: Gracias, @Alfabravo y @Duston! Entonces debería de eliminar en PHP todo lo que haya en path??

Comment: Tu wamp parece usar un php 7.4 pero en tus variables de entorno dejas disponibles los ejecutables de php 8.1.0. Eso hace que cuando hagas `php` en la terminal, uses la versión 8.1.0 y eso posiblemente afecte lo que intenta hacer wamp. No obligues a wamp a usar cosas mediante variables de entorno

Comment: @Alfabravo, entonces debería de desinstalar PHP 8.1.0?

Comment: Quita. El. Registro. De. Las. Variables. De. Entorno.

Comment: @Alfabravo, gracias!